# How to define vkCreateXcbSurfaceKHR in Erupted-V2?

Tags: d, vulkan

I'm trying to use XCB with Vulkan bindings [Erupted-V2](https://github.com/ParticlePeter/Erupted-V2) but I'm getting an error:

```
source/gfxdevicevulkan.d(231,24): Error: undefined identifier vkCreateXcbSurfaceKHR
```

Here's my dub.json:

```
{
"name": "dvulkanbase",
"targetType": "executable",
"description": "Vulkan boilerplate",
"license": "MIT",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "linux",
        "platforms": ["linux"],
        "versions": ["VK_USE_PLATFORM_XCB_KHR"],
        "libs": [ "X11", "Xi", "Xrandr", "pthread", "Xxf86vm","GL", "GLU", "Xinerama", "Xcursor" ],
      "dependencies": {
        "bindbc-sdl": "~>0.19.0",
        "erupted_v2": ">=1.1.71",
          "xlib-d": "~>0.1.1",
          "xcb-d": "~>2.1.0"
      }
    },
    {
        "name": "windows",
        "platforms": ["windows"],
        "versions": ["VK_USE_PLATFORM_WIN32_KHR"],
      "dependencies": {
        "bindbc-sdl": "~>0.19.0",
        "erupted_v2": ">=1.1.71"
      }
    }
]
}
```

Here's my imports in the file that uses vkCreateXcbSurfaceKHR:

```
import core.stdc.string;
import erupted;
import erupted.vulkan_lib_loader;
import matrix4x4;
import std.conv;
import std.exception;
import std.stdio;
version(linux)
{
    import X11.Xlib_xcb;
    public import xcb.xcb;
    import erupted.platform_extensions;
    mixin Platform_Extensions!VK_USE_PLATFORM_XCB_KHR;
}
```

Here's the relevant section of the calling code:

```
class GfxDeviceVulkan
{

   this( int width, int height, void* windowHandleOrWindow, void* display, uint window )
    {
        loadGlobalLevelFunctions();
        VkApplicationInfo appinfo;
        appinfo.pApplicationName = "VulkanBase";
        appinfo.apiVersion = VK_MAKE_VERSION( 1, 0, 2 );

        version(linux)
        {
            const(char*)[3] extensionNames = [
                                        "VK_KHR_surface",
                                        "VK_KHR_xcb_surface",
                                        "VK_EXT_debug_utils",
                                        ];
        }
    
        uint extensionCount = 0;
        vkEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties( null, &extensionCount, null );

        auto extensionProps = new VkExtensionProperties[]( extensionCount );
        vkEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties( null, &extensionCount, extensionProps.ptr );
    
        uint layerCount = 0;
        vkEnumerateInstanceLayerProperties( &layerCount, null );

        auto layerProps = new VkLayerProperties[]( layerCount );
        vkEnumerateInstanceLayerProperties( &layerCount, layerProps.ptr );

        const(char*)[1] validationLayers = ["VK_LAYER_KHRONOS_validation"];
    
        VkInstanceCreateInfo createinfo;
        createinfo.sType = VkStructureType.VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_INSTANCE_CREATE_INFO;
        createinfo.pApplicationInfo = &appinfo;
        createinfo.enabledExtensionCount = isDebug ? cast(uint)extensionNames.length : 2;
        createinfo.ppEnabledExtensionNames = extensionNames.ptr;
        createinfo.enabledLayerCount = isDebug ? validationLayers.length : 0;
        createinfo.ppEnabledLayerNames = isDebug ? validationLayers.ptr : null;

        enforceVk( vkCreateInstance( &createinfo, null, &instance ) );

        loadInstanceLevelFunctions( instance );

        version(linux)
        {
            auto xcbInfo = VkXcbSurfaceCreateInfoKHR(
          VkStructureType.VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_XCB_SURFACE_CREATE_INFO_KHR,
              null,
              0,
              XGetXCBConnection( cast(xcb_connection_t*)display ),
              window
                );
            enforceVk( vkCreateXcbSurfaceKHR( instance, &xcbInfo, null, &surface ) );
        }
```

How to fix the error?

Comment: your code doesn't look obviously wrong to me... do you use `private` at all? a private thing would trigger that error even if it existed.

Comment: @AdamD.Ruppe I'm not sure what you mean about `private` use (where?), so I pasted more code to show how I'm calling `vkCreateXcbSurfaceKHR`.